# Indifference curve in income and substitution effects

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-theory

i have this task:

*"Mary spends her totally daily budget (30 euro) for chocolate and cakes. The price of chocolate bar is 5 euro and price of slice of cake is 2 euro. Now the price of slice of cake is 6 euro.*

*1)Represent graphically the income and the substitution effects of this price increase, if there is imperfect substitutability between chocolate and cakes. Consider all possible cases.*

*2)In a diagram show the income effect  and the substitution effect of this price increase on consumption of both goods if they are perfect (on-to-one) substitution.*

*3)In a diagram show the income effect  and the substitution effect of this price increase on consumption of both goods if they are perfect (on-to-one) complements."*

How can i construct indifference curve for this stuff? I found articles how to represents it but i dont understand how to make curve (mean which combination should i choose and how find its).

So i know that we choose combinations of items and construct curve based of it, but how can i know which combinations should we choose? Like 5 chocolate and 2 cakes or 5 chocolates and 3 cakes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: okay, i edited it

Comment: In 1) do you know what "*imperfect substitutability*" means? In 2) "*they are perfect (on-to-one) substitution*".